# Can we use same route for authenticated and non-authenticated users in laravel with same controller and same view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```php
// route which should be used by authenticated and unauthenticated user 
Route::get('user/send-parcel', 'User\SenderController@sendParcerl');
```

I have tried to add this route in web (outside this auth middleware). It works fine but in my controller i have to add user id if the user is logged in if the user is not logged in the `user_id` field should contain the value of `NULL`.

```php
$user = Auth::user();
$parcel->user_id = isset($user) ? $user->id : NULL;
```

The main problem is if i put the route outside of Auth middleware than it will not get the Auth in my controller. so the code works fine with unauthenticated user but for authenticated user it also put `NULL` in `user_id` field

Comment: Can you post your routes?

Comment: please show us the controller function `sendParcerl()` code. Do you need to have a user->id or it can be null?

Comment: Is this api auth or session auth?

Comment: Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:user'], function () { Route::get('send-parcel', 'User\SenderController@sendParcerl');  });    but i want this route to be used in auth and unauth user so i put it outside from this middleware but in result in my controller it gives me NULL if user is logged in and trying to add the data

Comment: Your route is protected by Auth middleware, so you can either remove the route middleware, remove this route from the middleware or write another route that point to the same controller@function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
In your controller you have to add construct with your own middleware.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

        $this->user = $request->user('api');

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

The most important part here is

```
$request->user('api');
```

If your routing is public (without any middleware for restriction) it will be using all information accessible publicly, so there won't be session, token, etc.
Normal usage of **$request->user();** won't work.

Luckily **$request->user()** can take an argument

```
 /**
 * Get the user making the request.
 *
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function user($guard = null)
{
    return call_user_func($this->getUserResolver(), $guard);
}
```

so if you do **$request->user('api')**, it will retrieve the user using the api guard, because those informations are accessible in 'api' guard.

Now in your code you can check if $this->user is null (null it will be not logged user, object it will be logged user).

Source: Answer #1, point 3rd here https://www.py4u.net/discuss/32099

Answer (score -2):

The simple response is Yes, you can.

How it work, if you take a look at this page: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#authentication-quickstart

You will see a section explaining how to check if the user is log in.

**Determining If The Current User Is Authenticated**

To determine if the user is already logged into your application, you may use the check method on the Auth facade, which will return true if the user is authenticated:

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    if (Auth::check()) {
        // The user is logged in...
    }
```

So, in your controller, after adding the Auth facade, you can do this:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    // do something with an authenticated user
} else {
   // do something with a non-authenticated user
}
// shared code between all kind of users
```

As mentioned into the documentation of Laravel, most of the time it's recommended to use a middleware and redirect to different controller.

Comment: well the probleem is it goes into else part if the user is logged in (WITHOUT AUTH MIDDLEWARE ROUTE)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean. Auth::check() return true or false. It doesn't redirect anything, it's simply looking if the user is logged in. There is a difference between the Auth middleware and the Auth facade.